# IntelliJ Unable to Compile Scala Slick CaseClassShape

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, slick

I'm trying to create a Slick table definition mapped to a simple case class. Following the instructions [here](http://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/userdefined.html#monomorphic-case-classes), I came up with (copied) the following code.

```scala
    case class User(id: Int, name: String, email: String, phone: String)
    case class LiftedUser(id: Rep[Int], name: Rep[String], email: Rep[String], phone: Rep[String])
    implicit object UserShape extends CaseClassShape(LiftedUser.tupled, User.tupled)
```

When I run `sbt compile`, the project compiles fine. However, IntelliJ is giving me an error:

```
Type mismatch. Required: LiftedTuple => LiftedCaseClass, found: ((Rep[Int], Rep[String], Rep[String], Rep[String])) => LiftedUser
```

I guess in the grand scheme of things, it's not a huge deal, but it is rather annoying. Is this a compiler setting or something along those lines that I need to adjust?

- IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3
- Scala plugin 2020.3.18
- Adopt OpenJDK 15
- scala 2.13.3
- slick 3.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Did you use [code-generation](http://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/code-generation.html)?
It is hard to manually create a class that maps to a table.

Or, you can use the [PlainSQL syntax](http://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/sql.html) as shown here.

```
// Case classes for our data
case class Supplier(id: Int, name: String, street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String)
case class Coffee(name: String, supID: Int, price: Double, sales: Int, total: Int)

// Result set getters
implicit val getSupplierResult = GetResult(r => Supplier(r.nextInt, r.nextString, r.nextString,
  r.nextString, r.nextString, r.nextString))
implicit val getCoffeeResult = GetResult(r => Coffee(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<))
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess i didn't create the link properly at first, edited to fix that. That goes to the slick doc that shows where I am getting this syntax from. But no, I haven't tried the code generation yet. Again, it compiles fine using sbt, but IntelliJ is having trouble making sense of it.

Comment: I'd like to open the project in IntelliJ on my local machine. Can you upload a project to github or somewhere where I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sure, here's a minimal repro: https://github.com/anqit/repro-65433996

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Type Hints, probably in IntelliJ or Scala-plugin. Even though it looks like an error, there is no execution problem, so I guess you have to ignore it. 
And, there was also a bug in type inference in a Slick issue that will be addressed in the FUTURE... https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1541